# Getting error when signing apk

Tags: java, android, kivy, jarsigner, buildozer

Iv'e just made an apk file in kivy using buildozer with https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kivy-users/pBtbg8aSlNo as reference:

```
$ cd
$ mkdir keystores
$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore ./keystores/xyz.keystore -alias XYZ -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
$ cd XYZ
$ buildozer android release
$ cd
$ jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore ./keystores/xyz.keystore ./xyz/bin/XYZ-0.0.1-release-unsigned.apk XYZ
```

I get following error:

> jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load: Invalid keystore format

My Java version is:

```
bash-4.2$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_65-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 25.65-b01, mixed mode)
```

Comment: use android tool for signing

Comment: Thanks for the idea, @Shubham. I suppose you mean Android studio: (http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). As I've understood it, can that program only sign while building the apk, whereas jarsigner is the only way of signing already existing apk files. Am I right?

Comment: Android tool is available for both android studio as well as for eclipse.

Comment: Yes, tool first build the application (but i think u can uncheck auto build) then it will only check for LINT. If their is no error during lint checking your can generate a signed .apk. Hope you got your answer

Comment: The problem is now solved. There was a conflict between oracles java compiler and the gcc-java compiler on my Slackware system. Here's the solution: (http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/jdk-portecle-error-4175561020/page2.html)